# UIImagePickerController activity indicator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

When getting an image from the camera with a UIImagePickerController and AllowsEditing=YES, there is a pretty significant delay from when the user presses choose to when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called. I'd like to use [DejalBezelActivityView](http://www.dejal.com/blog/2012/02/dejalactivityview) to display an activity indicator during this time.  I'm not sure where I can put my call to:

```
[DejalBezelActivityView activityViewForView:(UIImagePickerController view goes here) withLabel:@"Processing..."];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have such a control with UIImagePickerController. You can of course create your own photo controller with AVFoundation. It takes some time as it needs to create the image...